# How to use context free grammars?

Tags: rascal

Could someone help me with using context free grammars. Up until now I've used regular expressions to remove comments, block comments and empty lines from a string so that it can be used to count the PLOC. This seems to be extremely slow so I was looking for a different more efficient method.

I saw the following post: [What is the best way to ignore comments in a java file with Rascal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179175/what-is-the-best-way-to-ignore-comments-in-a-java-file-with-rascal)

I have no idea how to use this, the help doesn't get me far as well. When I try to define the line used in the post I immediately get an error.

```
lexical SingleLineComment = "//" ~[\n] "\n";
```

Could someone help me out with this and also explain a bit about how to setup such a context free grammar and then to actually extract the wanted data?

Kind regards,

Bob

Answer (score 0):

First this will help: the `~` in Rascal CFG notation is not in the language, the negation of a character class is written like so: `![\n]`.

To use a context-free grammar in Rascal goes in three steps:

1. write it, like for example the syntax definition of the Func language here: http://docs.rascal-mpl.org/unstable/Recipes/#Languages-Func
2. Use it to parse input, like so:

   // This is the basic parse command, but be careful it will not accept spaces and newlines before and after the TopNonTerminal text:
   Prog myParseTree = parse(#Prog, "example string");

   // you can do the same directly to an input file:
   Prog myParseTree = parse(#TopNonTerminal, |home:///myProgram.func|);

   // if you need to accept layout before and after the program, use a "start nonterminal":
   start[Prog] myParseTree = parse(#start[TopNonTerminal], |home:///myProgram.func|);
   Prog myProgram = myParseTree.top;

   // shorthand for parsing stuff:
   myProgram = [Prog] "example";
   myProgram = [Prog] |home:///myLocation.txt|;
3. Once you have the tree you can start using `visit` and `/` deepmatch to extract information from the tree, or write recursive functions if you like. Examples can be found here: http://docs.rascal-mpl.org/unstable/Recipes/#Languages-Func , but here are some common idioms as well to extract information from a parse tree:

   // produces the source location of each node in the tree:
   myParseTree@\loc

   // produces a set of all nodes of type Stat 
   { s | /Stat s := myParseTree }

   // pattern match an if-then-else and bind the three expressions and collect them in a set: 
   { e1, e2, e3 | (Stat) `if <Exp e1> then <Exp e2> else <Exp e3> end` <- myExpressionList }

   // collect all locations of all sub-trees (every parse tree is of a non-terminal type, which is a sub-type of `Tree`. It uses |unknown:///| for small sub-trees which have not been annotated for efficiency's sake, like literals and character classes:
   [ t@\loc?|unknown:///| | /Tree t := myParseTree ]

That should give you a start. I'd go try out some stuff and look at more examples. Writing a grammar is a nice thing to do, but it does require some trial and error methods like writing a regex, but even more so.

For the grammar you might be writing, which finds source code comments but leaves the rest as "any character" you will need to use the longest match disambiguation a lot:

```
lexical Identifier = [a-z]+ !>> [a-z]; // means do not accept an Identifier if there is still [a-z] to add to it; so only the longest possible Identifier will match.
```

This kind of context-free grammar is called an "Island Grammar" metaphorically, because you will write precise rules for the parts you want to recognize (the comments are "Islands") while leaving the rest as everything else (the rest is "Water"). See https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=837160